# Jhipster how to configure to run maven test cases

Tags: jhipster

I have some java test cases that i would like to run without webapp loading as there are only service/repository test case, but how to run them with the database part only ?
I tried several way even in loading all dependencies but i have some problems with metrics, loading, is there an easy way to do that ?

Else running spring-boot run works very well...

Maybe having a profile for test would be greats.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem with you..
i tricked with split to some configuration which only loaded necessary config...

Load Other Bean :

```
@Configuration
public class ContextTest {

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine() {
        return new SpringTemplateEngine();
    }
}
```

Load Security Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.qinti.vi.security"
})
public class SecurityContextConfigTest {
    @Bean
    public SpringSecurityAuditorAware springSecurityAuditorAware() {
        return new SpringSecurityAuditorAware();
    }
}
```

Load Service :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.qinti.vi.service"
})
public class ServiceContextConfigTest {
}
```

And Load some Config From Unit Test :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {
        SecurityContextConfigTest.class,
        DatabaseConfiguration.class,
        ServiceContextConfigTest.class,
        SecurityConfiguration.class,
        MailConfiguration.class,
        ThymeleafConfiguration.class,
        AuditEventConverter.class,
        ContextTest.class,
})
@WebAppConfiguration
@Import(MongoConfiguration.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Inject
    private PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository;

// omited
```